# curve_fit: the function uses function from the other class: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python

I am trying to find the best fit parameters for a function by scipy.optimize.curve_fit
here is the code

```
def y_position(b, E, time):

    a = 0.75/100
    b = 40
    T = 40
    dty = 7*60
    e=pickle.load(open("aclass.die", "rb"))
    array = []
    return_y = 0
    for f in e.frag:
        t = 0
        while t < time:
              f.position_in_y(f.num, a, E, dty, b, T)
              t += dty
        array.append(f.ypos)
#rescale
    minus = max(array)
    for j in range(len(array)):
        array[j] = array[j]-minus
    divid = min(array)
    for i in range(len(array)):
        array[i] = array[i]/divid

    for n in range(len(e.frag)):
        if e.frag[n].num == b:
           return_y = array[n]
    return return_y


exper_y=[0, 1.0, 0.780, 0.640, 0.240, 0.680]
x =[638, 78, 643, 71, 534, 303]

po = [28, 500]
po, cov = optimize.curve_fit(y_position, x, exper_y, p0=po)

print po  
exit()
```

I've defined the classes needed in other files and import that at the beginning for sure. The `position_in_y` is a function in frag class
my function is a bit complex but still logical I guess.
I got the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'
```

after I run it. I cannot understand why it got that. Any help please!!!
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are performing subtraction of a list from an int somewhere. does it say where the error is?

Comment: In your posted code, the only place you are doing subtraction is `array[j] = array[j]-minus` which in that case, I would look at what `array.append(f.ypos)` really is. It would seem `f.ypos` is a `list`, not an `int`.

Comment: I added 'print' between comments and the is no problem with the arrays:       array:[44.88686447774176, 36.63538815686307, 38.45383342957665, 39.62199489783976, 42.941553461815964, 39.071347376799686]
minus=44.8868644777
divid=-8.25147632088
final array=[-0.0, 1.0, 0.7796218274162203, 0.6380518315953125, 0.23575308711770535, 0.7047850438868846]
and the returned value: 0.638051831595

Comment: but after I comment these codes it shows the error again. I do not know anywhere I did subtraction except for array[j]=array[j]-minus